# Share file via Intent is Ok even if the file type don't match

Tags: android

I use the following code to share a image, it's Ok if the image type is png.
But I'm very surprised that it's still OK if the the image type is jpeg. Why? Thanks!

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file://"+arrPath[i]);

sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Comment: The intent thinks it is "image/png" because you setting that explictly. You can send anything in there and it still would think it is an image. You could instead do URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(extension) to allow it to select the right Mime

Comment: can i use this code to share image from drawable folder? if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the `Intent` system works.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#iobjs

> An `Intent` object is a bundle of information. It contains information of interest to the component that receives the intent (such as the action to be taken and the data to act on) plus information of interest to the Android system (such as the category of component that should handle the intent and instructions on how to launch a target activity).

The responsibility of actually dealing with the file is left with the applications that register to handle that kind of intent. At this stage it's not going to care/check whether the file is a jpg or a png.

You're basically saying "hey, sharing applications! I have a png for you!"

I'm not sure what exactly you are after but if you don't want jpgs to be shared you need to handle that in your code.